# Delete row in sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, delete-row

I have a sqlite database which store different multiple user's data. I wanted to ask how to delete specific row in the database? I'm not really familiar with database type of stuff. Currently I have a delete function that used to delete one of the user's information in the database. But I'm not really sure how to delete the entire row. (I got emailid, first & last name and ssid in my database. )

```
    public void delete_user(String ssid) {
    Log.i(TAG,"delete_user ssid["+ssid+"]...");

    String[] valuesWhere = new String[1];
    valuesWhere[0] = ssid;

    this.getWritableDatabase().delete("user", "ssid=?", valuesWhere);
}
```

Should I declare every value that I wanted to delete? I wanted to know whether is there another way that able to delete specific row of data. Any comments will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I declare every value that I wanted to delete? I wanted to know whether is there another way that able to delete specific row of data.

Your current code will delete every row that matches the `ssid` passed to `delete_user(ssid)`. If `ssid` is a unique column (no duplicate values) it will delete one row at most.

> But I'm not really sure how to delete the entire row.

Understand that `SQLiteDatabase#delete()` will never partially delete a row.

Comment: So it means that the above code is basically delete the entire column? Then how should it be if I wanted to delete a row?

Comment: No, I'm sorry. `delete()` removes entire row(s). You cannot "delete" a column with `delete()`. For _any row_ that matches the data passed in the second and third parameters (in your case `"ssid=?", valuesWhere`), the _whole row_ will be deleted.